# Visual video subtitle (srt) synchronization

Tags: subtitles, framerate

I have a video file and a subtitle file. They are not synchronized and re-synchronizing the subtitles to the video according to the frame-rates of the two is not working.

Is there a tool where I visually can open both files and then set a few markings on the video timeline and specify the corresponding places in the subtitles, and then generate a correctly synchronized subtitles file?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, re-syncing subtitles by framerate and delay is pretty much an impossible task without a visual timeline.

Try:

### [Subtitle Edit](http://www.nikse.dk/SubtitleEdit) for Windows

[image: Subtitle Edit main window with waveform and video player]

### [Subtitle Editor](http://home.gna.org/subtitleeditor/) for *nix

[image: Subtitle Editor main window with video, waveform and keyframes]

They don't have video timelines, but both are visual editors with waveforms/audio timelines. Both are also FOSS.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the subtitles and their internal distances are correct, though in time incorrectly scaled and perhaps with a constant offset, you only need two measurements (at what times two separate lines in the .srt file actually occur on screen) to decide both the base offset and the scaling offset (linear algebra: for two unknowns you need two independent equations).

http://subshifter.bitsnbites.eu/ takes two such input times and rescales the .srt file. It's real easy to calculate the offsets even by hand, but it's nice to have help rewriting the timings.

Tip: use the first and the last subtitle entries as measurement values to get the best results.

If the texts are still not correct, then you have subs for a cut version or something similar. You can use the above technique on each corresponding portion of the two video files, but it will be more work. It probably beats manually retiming every single subtitle, though.

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves me right [Aegisub](http://www.aegisub.org/) can do that. It's been a few years since I worked on any subtitle projects, but I think you had to determine what the framerate was for the subtitles and the framerate of the video you want to sync them with and it can apply the changes to the entire subtitle file.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Subtitle Workshop](http://www.urusoft.net/products.php?cat=sw) for this. Basically you open the subtitle and the movie in subtitle workshop, and then choose two scenes in the movie (preferably at the beginning and the end) and link them to the correct but delayed subtitle. Workshop subtitle will recalculate the time and fix the delay.

This video walks you step by step: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SsgitAR2aeU

What took me hours to fix (when the delay is worse at the end than at the beginning), only takes a couple of minutes.

Comment: There is a good explanation, here : http://v2.subscene.com//forums/t/16689.aspx,  for why the delay increases throughout the movie: it's a re-framing consequences: